# error running rails server "Failed to load libmysql.dll"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am trying to run the command rails server in the folder where is my ruby application but is failing. I am using the followig versions:

Ruby 1.9.3.

Gem 2.0.3.

Rails 4.2.1.

MySQL server 5.5

[image]

Someone know how can I fix it?

Comment: This is a known bug for Win users. There are several solutions available. Have you tried 1) Downloading MySQL Connector? 2) Making sure you are running 32bit verision of MySQL? 3) replacing the libmysql.dll file? See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7

Comment: Hi dimitry_N. Yes, I have installed the MySQL connector/c 6.1.5; 32 bit version of MySQL and replace the libmysql.dll too. I check the thread you post and try some of those solutions and I'm still getting the same error. I don't know if I should uninstall everything and try again.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I, myself, have spent at least two weeks trying to figure it out. In my case it was the x64 version of the MySQL Server.

Comment: Well I finally found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368332/failed-to-load-libmysql-dll-file-using-ruby-on-rails-3. It was the version of the MySQL connector, now I am using the 6.0.2 version and it works fine.

Comment: smooth! Glad you got it sorted out!