# Rails 5 and Ruby 2.3.3 Failed to load libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

Getting below error message logged in the console while starting the server for an application created with mysql database.

```
Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\mysql2-0.4.7-x86-mingw32\vendor\libmysql.dll
```

Environment Details :

```
Window 7 64 bit
Rails 5.0.4
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
mysqld  Ver 5.7.18 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

Post install message from mysql2 ruby gem received below message on the console.

```
You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.10.
It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were retrieved from:
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.10-win32.zip

This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice in vendor/README.
```

I have tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368332/failed-to-load-libmysql-dll-file-using-ruby-on-rails-3) but did not work.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downgrading mysql2 rubygem from version 0.4.7 to 0.3.21 solved my issue.

Below steps I followed

```
rails new blog -d mysql # created application with mysql as database
gem uninstall mysql2 #uninstalled mysql2-0.4.7
Gemfile :
    gem 'mysql2', '0.3.21' #Gemfile changed mysql2 version to 0.3.21
bundle update mysql2 #installed mysql2-0.3.21 version
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How you did you came to know about this version of the mysql2 gem will work? please share

Comment: Actually In my system I had one application running in Rails 4 and mysql2 gem version 0.3.21, which was working fine. Same machine I had another app with rails 5 and mysql2 version 0.4.7, this one was giving issue. So I was very sure its not related to MYSQL installation. So I downgraded mysql2 version 0.3.21 as in Rails 4 app and luckily it did work for me. Before trying this I did uninstall and install of mysql and even OS :) almost 2-3 times, my bad I did not got to know this trick earlier.

Comment: Thanks, I came across the same error after installing rails 2.2 for windows from http://railsinstaller.org/en, and follow you trick it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update to this thread, specifying the platform of the gem did the job for me;

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby
```

And here is my version details:

```
Windows OS
Ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 5.1.6
Gemfile:
  gem 'mysql2', '0.5.1'
```