# Ruby-on-rails cannot connect to mysql2; Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I'm on Windows 10 and am a complete beginner programmer. I am using Ruby 2.4.2, Rails 5.1.4 and am following a Lynda course on how to run Rails 5 on Windows. 
There's a part near the end where the tutor says to enter:

```
    >rails db:schema:dump
```

to test whether you've established a connection to the MySQL by create a file inside the created project.
This is what I get when I enter the above command:

```
C:\Users\notmyactualuser\Documents\Sites\demo_project>rails db:schema:dump
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2
C:/Users/notmyactualuser/Documents/Sites/demo_project/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/notmyactualuser/Documents/Sites/demo_project/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/notmyactualuser/Documents/Sites/demo_project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The tutor doesn't address what to do with potential errors and I can't seem to find an answer. I want to build a login form using RoR and am trying to grasp the basics (clearly failing). If possible, can I get help with the above and be directed to an easy, simple, "how-to" on building a login form?
Thanks a lot.

P.S. My first post, so please go easy on me, lol.

UPDATE: So I used the  command on CMD and it looks like it's successful. Can somebody point me to how to get it working with Rails?

UPDATE 2: I put in the command that Hoa requested and I got this:

ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["mysql2"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"

## UPDATE 3: I did as Satishkakumar said and I got this:

You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.6.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were retrieved from:
  http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip

This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice in vendor/README.

======================================================================================================

Looks like it's all sorted now? Please let me know if there's any more.

Comment: Installing MySQL + Rails on Windows can be pretty complicated. Are you sure you followed all the Lynda steps (install MySQL + install MySQL gem)? You could also look at other ways to install Rails on Windows. For example using the Win10 Bash subsystem instead: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 or using MSYS2: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059

Comment: The error means mysql2 gem has not been installed successfully. Make sure you get that done first.

Comment: @Hoa Care to elaborate on how to make sure I get that done first?

Comment: @Burn1ngFr0st7 From C:\Users\notmyactualuser\Documents\Sites\demo_project run `bundle install mysql2`, you should see a bunch of errors. Put the errors in your question for our information.

Comment: I've added the error I received into my question above. I appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 1):

I think its issue of installing mysql2 gem in system. Follow below steps to install.

1. In Gemfile add the line

   ```
   gem 'mysql2', '0.3.21'
   ```
2. And run bundle install from project folder in CMD.

   ```
   bundle install mysql2
   ```

This might solve your issue. Let me know in comment section if your issue still persists.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I got the same error I've listed in UPDATE 2 above. What does this mean?

Comment: Try just 'bundle install' from project directory.

Comment: Have a look at my latest update. I think you might have just solved my problem, mate.

Comment: You should go ahead with executing command 'rails db:schema:dump'. If any issue refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912535/rails-5-and-ruby-2-3-3-failed-to-load-libmysql-dll and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368332/failed-to-load-libmysql-dll-file-using-ruby-on-rails-3